# Problem with SwiftUI: Vertical ScrollView with Button

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, scrollview

I'm quite new to programming so please excuse any dumb questions. I'm trying to make a ScrollView with the content being buttons. Although the button prints to console, when shown in the simulator the button displays as a large blue rectangle rather than displaying the image I would like it to.

Code Regarding ScrollView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
   [Simulator Display][1] 



    VStack {

        Image("logo")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .padding(.leading, 50)
            .padding(.trailing, 50)
            .padding(.top, 20)
            .padding(.bottom, -20)
        Spacer()

        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Button(action: {
                    //ToDo
                    print("Executed")
                }) {
                    Image("Logo")
                }
            }
        }





    }
}
```

}

Simulator Display:

[image]

Image(Placeholder for now) I want to be displayed:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the image please

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2j4D52o

Comment: Sorry about that for some reason its not allowing me to include it in the post.

Comment: So the image is a blue square? You can paste the link to that square on the post, not on the comment, but just the square, not like the above

Comment: Okay, my apologies all should be provided in the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried it an yeah it was very weird. Anyway, here is an example of how you can include the image. Just take the portion of the Button and paste it

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
              print("button pressed")

            }) {
                Image("image")
                .renderingMode(.original)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @DevinHadley I modified the answer with a more optimal approach, check it out

Comment: Awesome that looks great. I will accept it right now as well.

Comment: Okay its been a while and the solution works perfectly! Just coming back here to let anyone know what is causing the problem. I realized that SwiftUI automatically renders buttons blue. By setting the renderingMode to original, the image is displayed as its normal state instead of turning blue.